# How to check if a Youtube ID is valid with Nokogori and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, nokogiri

I want to isolate the pageInfo -> TotalResults in order to check if the link is valid (= 1)

This is video_controller.rb:

```
 submitted_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id="+@results[:id]+"&key="+ENV["KEY_YOUTUBE"]
 link_result = Nokogiri::HTML(open(submitted_link))
```

I get this result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/GWU-
KIYwNWh_dAkOcA5xDaFhS48\"",
 "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 1,
   "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
 {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-
  MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/wp71OkMYYohvwOjzLL_4NN8r7w0\"",
   "id": "m9h7qCdgPN4"
  }
 ]
}
```

Have you an idea?

Comment: Try with `HTTParty` or `RestClient` instead of `nokogiri`. You can get as json and you will get result as json and parse it. Like `link_result["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] == 1`

Comment: Thank you a lot :)
By doing : youtube_link = JSON.parse(response)['pageInfo']['totalResults'] it's working very well.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool. Nokogiri is an HTML/XML parser. The output isn't XML or HTML, it's JSON.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". It's really important to understand the basic formats of data that can be returned by HTTP-based services.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a task for Nokogiri as Nokogiri is for parsing HTML or XML. The documentation starts with:

> Nokogiri parses and searches XML/HTML very quickly, and also has correctly
>   implemented CSS3 selector support as well as XPath 1.0 support.

Instead, your output is JSON and needs to be parsed by the JSON class.
This is untested code but is in the ballpark:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

foo = JSON[open("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=#{@results[:id]}&key=#{ENV['KEY_YOUTUBE']}").read]
```

Once parsed, you'll be returned a Ruby object, in this case a hash. Meditate on this:

```
require 'json'

str = DATA.read
foo = JSON[str]
# => {"kind"=>"youtube#videoListResponse",
#     "etag"=>"\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/GWU-KIYwNWh_dAkOcA5xDaFhS48\"",
#     "pageInfo"=>{"totalResults"=>1, "resultsPerPage"=>1},
#     "items"=>
#      [{"kind"=>"youtube#video",
#        "etag"=>"\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/wp71OkMYYohvwOjzLL_4NN8r7w0\"",
#        "id"=>"m9h7qCdgPN4"}]}

foo['pageInfo']['totalResults'] # => 1

__END__
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/GWU-KIYwNWh_dAkOcA5xDaFhS48\"",
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
},
"items": [
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/wp71OkMYYohvwOjzLL_4NN8r7w0\"",
  "id": "m9h7qCdgPN4"
  }
]
}
```